# GNOME Tweaks > Window Titlebars Settings Don't Work

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweaks

If I go into GNOME Tweaks > Window Titlebars and change anything in the "Titlebar Buttons" section, nothng works. What I am particularly aiming to do is make the buttons go to the left instead of the right, but the button does absolutely nothing. How can I fix this? Is this a Tweaks bug?

The setting has worked before, but now it doesn't. I am wondering if my KDE Plasma installation has messed it up or something, although I know that shouldn't be the case. The reason I suspect KDE Plasma is because the titlebar left/right toggle worked before I installed KDE Plasma but now it doesn't (I uninstalled KDE Plasma a while back, for a different reason).

I have tried restarting GNOME. Although probably pointless, I even restarted the computer. I tried using dconf-editor to change it, and I tried gsettings. Nothing works!

How can I fix this?

Comment: KDE Plasma is not Gnome you are trying to make changes to a different DE then you are running.

Comment: @David no that's not what I said. What I DID say was that I HAD kde plasma but it seeme like for some reason my installing it has messed up the GNOME interface.

Comment: @Nmath Sorry! I think I just installed `plasma-desktop` with apt. I removed it by just doing apt remove. Is there something wrong with my system now that I removed it or something?

Comment: If there are problems then I would say yes. It can be hard to find out what is causing the problem exactly because DEs involve dozens of packages and configs. Perhaps you can create a new user because that will generate new configs under the new home folder.  But if that doesn't work and you can't narrow down the problem, you may find that a reinstall is faster. I suggest that you maybe "Try Ubuntu" from a USB of several [flavours](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) before you commit. GNOME is not designed with customization in mind. Some would say it's openly hostile to customization.

Comment: @Nmath I made another user account and everything in GNOME seems to be working...but I just wish I could keep my normal account because I have everything set up perfectly (besides the problem in this question :P). Besides that, do you think there are any problems in the overall underlying system?

Comment: @Nmath I guess the problem is that you can't really remove other DEs. I found a long command that deleted pretty much all of kde. The only problem is that I don't know what all the configuration files in my home directory are (because they're still here). Is there a way to do something like `rm ~/.config/plasma*` or something? I want to completely go back to gnome.

Comment: If everything is working fine in a new user then there's probably not anything wrong with the underlying system. The issues that arise from changing DEs or using multiple DEs are usually because of one or more conflicting configs under the home folder. So that would explain why a new user doesn't have the problem. Your old account will include a lot of application-specific configs under `/home/username/.config/`. It might help speed up setting up a new user to selectively copy those into the same path in your new home folder.

Comment: You can try that, but the problem probably isn't with any leftover configs unique to plasma but probably with configs for applications used by both desktop environments. So there may be some trial and error involved in removing configs or copying configs from one user to another. In any case, make sure your backups are in order before messing around with it. It's good to know that you can spawn a new user but it's always better to be safe than sorry

Comment: Alright, thanks @Nmath I might just start a new user. However I did find out that under `~/.config`, there are a lot of files that start with the letter "k" which is for kde. I usually delete them, but I look inside them first to make sure they say anything about plasma in them before I delete.