# Install KDE Plasma Settings App Without Installing KDE Plasma

Tags: apt, gnome, settings, plasma

So I recently uninstalled KDE Plasma. There are some configuration files that are messing up my GNOME Settings (discussed in my other question [GNOME Tweaks > Window Titlebars Settings Don't Work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391157/gnome-tweaks-window-titlebars-settings-dont-work)).

How can I install the KDE Plasma settings app without installing the entire DE? When I try to use `sudo apt install systemsettings`, it asks for confirmation to install "the following packages," which includes literally every package that comes with KDE Plasma.

If unclear, the reason I want the KDE Plasma settings app is so I can change the settings in that app since I have no idea where the config files are. Since the config files are all in my home directory, the configs are being used by all DEs, and all DEs edit them, which is why changing them gets messy (as discussed in the link at the top of this question).

Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133898/discussion-between-someone-and-alex-fullam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDE system settings depend on `libc` libraries and `qt5` libraries. AFAIK it does not depend on the full KDE plasma-desktop, but the KDE desktop is one of the suggested and recommended packages.

You can install the package without installing the recommended packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends systemsettings
```

**NOTE**: The above command will install the KDE system settings. You won't be able to tweak GNOME desktop using KDE system settings though.